# Drupal Commerce: Allow anonymous users to choose password

Tags: 7, commerce, users

I'd like to allow anonymous users to make purchases on my store, however I don't want them to have to login and then change their password as their first port of call. Is there anyway I can collect a password from the customer during checkout, like it is possible to in Ubercart 3 and with LoginToboggan?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into modules that handle this use case. See below for examples:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_complete_registration

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_login_step

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra